# Can't connect to documentdb emulator in virtualbox

Tags: azure

I am trying to setup a DocumentDB emulator on my Win7 local, then found out it only supports Windows 10.
then I installed the emulator on Windows10 VirtualBox, I have no problem seeing the Emulator page using localhost.

however, when I try to connect from my Win7 local box to the emulator on Win10 virtualbox, I can't get a connection (either from browser pointing to https://localhost:8081/... or from code).

Is the DocumentDB Emulator only accessible from the machine running it?

1. i turned off windows firewall on Win10
2. I ran Emulator on port 443 on Win10
3. Virtualbox network config: NAT Port forwarding 8081 to 443  (i have similar config for SSH from Win7 to Linux VB that works)

thanks in advance

Comment: virtualbox? Do you mean VMs on Azure?

Comment: no, i meant Oracle VirtualBox so I could run Windows 10 in that VM running on my Windows 7.  I downloaded Win10 VirtualBox image from modern.ie

Comment: Have you succeeded? I can _kinda_ connect to it over direct ports (defaults are 10251, 10252, 10253, 10254), but I'm getting security errors, even after installing certificates.
I'm running mine in Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is how I succeeded.

First, install DocumentDBEmulatorCertificate from your VM to the host, as a trusted certificate. [Here you can find how to export it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates)

Then forward a port to 8081 with netsh:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=64000 connectport=8081 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: thanks for the hint.
Now with Fiddler, I can see it's related to Cert error, however, exporting and importing Cert and Port forward changes did not fix the problem!

Comment: Have you added it as a trusted root certificate? You have to choose that manually.

Comment: I added Cert to trusted authority storage, no luck.  

I also created a https website in VirtualBox, using the same DocumentDbEmulatorCertificate, I can open the site from host machine browser.  But I can't get a successful connection with DocumentDB emulator itself.

fiddler response: 
fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to localhost (for #15) failed. System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.